# ds4 controller triggers macos actions

Tags: macos, bluetooth, shortcut

i have a ps4/ds4 bluetooth game controller. when it is connected, macos reacts to some of its inputs, like for example a long press on "share" button makes a popup window to appear and ask me if i want to record the screen. another example, pressing the "ps" button makes macos to show macos launchpad (all installed apps in a fullscreen grid).
i would like to disable those shortcuts as it is annoying when i'm playing a game those actions get triggered and are damaging my gaming experience. (i'm getting taken out of the game, to macos launchpad, or i'm being asked by a popup if i want to record the screen..)
it's annoying. would someone knows how to make macos to stop reacting like that to some of my controller's input ?
by the way, my mac is a M1 from 2020 first generation, macos is latest 12.3.1 in case it matters.

Answer (score 0):

i've just noticed those are options in bluetooth manager for my gamepad. (bluetooth preference pane -> dualshock4 wireless controller). it has been pestering me for a while now and the solution was just under my nose all the time.